# What is the idiomatic way to create component inside component with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I what to `FooBlock` rerender only with foo change

```
export function FooBarComponent() {

  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(1)

  const [bar, setBar] = useState(1)

  const FooBlock = () => {
    console.log("render", foo)
    return <div>{foo}</div>
  }

  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => setFoo(x => x + 1)}>foo</button> {foo}
    <button onClick={() => setBar(x => x + 1)}>bar</button> {bar}
    <FooBlock/>
  </div>

}
```

I can do something like this

```
  const FooBlock = useMemo(() => React.memo(() => {
    console.log("render", foo)
    return <div>{foo}</div>
  }), [foo])
```

But it looks slightly weird. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a component inside a component. You could simply write it outside the component and pass props to it.

```
  const FooBlock = ({foo}) => {
    console.log("render", foo)
    return <div>{foo}</div>
  }
export function FooBarComponent() {

  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(1)

  const [bar, setBar] = useState(1)



  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => setFoo(x => x + 1)}>foo</button> {foo}
    <button onClick={() => setBar(x => x + 1)}>bar</button> {bar}
    <FooBlock foo={foo}/>
  </div>

}
```

Comment: Yes, I don't need but I would prefer to create a component inside component, so I don't need to pass all props inside it.